# Combining two similiar .js functions to one

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I know this is basic for most of you but im not that experienced on this language. So when i add both of the codes to functions.php they dont work. But it only works when i use only one of them. So im thinking maybe it would work if they both were in the same code lines. I tried to do that but couldnt make it work.

This is the first function:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction()
};
    
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 90 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 90)
    {
        document.getElementById("quadmenu_0")
                    .style.padding = "20px 0px";

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("quadmenu_0")
                    .style.padding = "180px 0px 40px";
            
    }
}
```

And this is the second function:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction()
};
    
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150)
    {
        document.getElementById("ast-mobile-header")
                    .style.backgroundColor = "red";

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ast-mobile-header")
                    .style.backgroundColor = "white";
            
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You want the contents of both those functions to execute?

Comment: So basically first one is to shrink my desktop version menu when its scrolled and second one is for mobile menu which is for different colors once they are scrolled like starting red but then turns white once its scrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call both functions within the onScroll listener. They will need to of course have different names (and best to choose something more logical than the below example)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction1()
    scrollFunction2()
};
```

```js
function scrollFunction1() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 90 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 90) {
      document.getElementById("quadmenu_0")
        .style.padding = "20px 0px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("quadmenu_0")
      .style.padding = "180px 0px 40px";      
  }
}
```

```js
function scrollFunction2() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
      document.getElementById("ast-mobile-header")
        .style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ast-mobile-header")
      .style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```